# JSON Data into Table Rows JavaScript

Tags: javascript, java, html, row

I have a list of Strings that changes with the change in input(Java). I want to create a table in Javascript which automatically adds the list objects into the table rows dynamically depending upon the size of the list. I dont know how to do this. Please help.

```
public String ListOfFieldNames() throws URISyntaxException{
    fieldNames = new ArrayList<>();
     URI jiraserverURI = new URI("https://jira.xxx.com");
     JiraRestClientFactory restClientfactory = new AsynchronousJiraRestClientFactory();
     JiraRestClient Client = restClientfactory.createWithBasicHttpAuthentication(jiraserverURI, username,
            password);

     GetCreateIssueMetadataOptionsBuilder oldoptions = new GetCreateIssueMetadataOptionsBuilder();
        GetCreateIssueMetadataOptionsBuilder withProjectKeys = oldoptions.withProjectKeys(User Input);
        GetCreateIssueMetadataOptionsBuilder withExpandedIssueTypesFields = withProjectKeys
                .withExpandedIssueTypesFields();
        GetCreateIssueMetadataOptions options = withExpandedIssueTypesFields.build();

        Iterable<CimProject> metsdata = Client.getIssueClient().getCreateIssueMetadata(options).claim();
        CimProject cim = metsdata.iterator().next();
        System.out.println();
        for (CimFieldInfo info : cim.getIssueTypes().iterator().next().getFields().values()) {

            if (info.isRequired()) {
                fieldNames.add(info.getName() + " * ");

            } else {
                fieldNames.add(info.getName());
            }

        }

        return new Gson().toJson(fieldNames);
}
```

UPDATE:
I want to know if this can help me.

```
    (document).ready(function () {
    $.getJSON('GetFieldName', function(resp){
        var table = document.createElement('table');

        $.each(resp, function(key, value)){

            //create a row and append the element in the cell
        }

    }
    // body...
})
```

I dont know how would I create a row and add the JSON data.

Comment: And stuff like `GetCreateIssueMetadataOptionsBuilder` is why I hate design patterns with a burning passion (unless my contempt should just be placed on long identifiers, rather than design patterns).

Comment: @Jashaszun I wish I could avoid using GetCreateIssueMetadataoptionsBuilder